# Accept string values in NSArray from the user

Tags: objective-c

hi i want to accept string values into the object of NSArray at run time from the user heres what i tried

```
-(void)fun
```

{

```
    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    for(int i =0;i<3;i++)
    {

        scanf("%s",&arr[i]);
    }
printf("Print values\n");
    for(int j =0; j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",arr[j]);
    }
}
```

i am getting an error can you please help me out regarding this and is their any alternative to scanf in objective c.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between NSArray and NSMutable Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491352/difference-between-nsarray-and-nsmutable-array)

Comment: This is **exactly the same** issue as the question **you** asked yesterday.  Read and act on the answers given to that question and you wouldn't need to ask this one.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` with a `%s` format will read the string into a C array, not an `NSArray` object.  You need to read the string into a C array, then make an `NSString` object to add to your `NSArray`.  You also need to have a mutable array to make your code work.  Example:

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
     char buf[100];
     scanf("%s", buf);
     NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:buf encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
     [arr addObject:str];
 }
```

You can use `NSLog()` to print your strings later on.

Answer (score 0):

use `NSMutableArray` instead; 
than you can use also

```
[arr addObject:tempVar];
```